# JQuery Validation Engine for dynamically added hidden input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I want to use the JQuery Validation Engine plugin to look over dynamically added hidden input fields.

At least one of this fields has to be there, when the form is submitted.

It tried to achieve this with the groupRequired Validator

http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#validators/grouprequired

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
                     <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#tagform").validationEngine();
                       });
                    </script>
        <form id="tagform">
               <input type="hidden" name="tags" id="tags-input" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="inc" value="locate">
                    <input type="hidden" class="validate[groupRequired[tagitem]]" name="validation">
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Tags">

        </form>
```

Added Fields look like:

```
 var formhtml ='<input type="hidden" name="tags[]" class="validate[groupRequired[tagitem]]" id="id'+itemid+'" parenttag="'+parent+'" value="'+itemid+'">';
                $("#tagform").append(formhtml);
```

At the moment it simply doesn't check for the hidden fields.

Any idea how to fix this or another approach ?

**Workaround**

Use a simple javaskript onSubmit Function to check occurens of tags

```
function checkForm(form)
{
var count = $('input[name="tags[]"]').length;
if(count == 0 ) {
   alert("Select at least one tag");       
   return false;
}
alert ("Count " + count)
return true;
}
```

Still would love to use Jquery Validation Engine

Comment: Have you tried adding them as `<input type="text" style="display: none" />"` instead?

Comment: nope but good idea ill try

Comment: doesn't make a difference but was worth a try

Comment: Are you running `$("#tagform").validationEngine();` after the elements have been added?

Comment: no ;) that maybe a problem later on , but what i want to achieve is that i got an error , when there was no field added at all

Comment: Try adding an ID to the elements

Comment: ok i added id to the initial field and the possible added fields, doesnt help, i always had trouble with this groupRequired validator

Comment: Another option could be HTM5 validation. If your browser supports it

Comment: i use a simply javaskript as workaround now, but would really like to use jquery validation / validation engine

Comment: What about an element with `style="visibility: hidden"` ?

Comment: visibility:hidden seems to work just tested with the tag manager

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instantiate JQuery Validation with validateNonVisibleFields

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#formID").validationEngine({validateNonVisibleFields: true,
        updatePromptsPosition:true});

       });
    </script>
```

Still you have the problem that Jquery / Javascript can not get a position of a hidden field. So use style visibility:hidden instead.

```
<input name="hiddenq2" type="text" value="" class="validate[required]" jqtop="500" id="form-validation-field-1" style="visibility: hidden">
```

You still might have to adjust a little bit with the promptPosition options but at least there is something showing up.

Comment: Hello,
I tried adding this option but still I coudn't able to see the error message for hidden field, could please tell me for which it will support ?