# jQuery ValidationEngine: How to validate hidden field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am using Jquery Validation Engine for my page. The issue I am facing is it doesn't validate field which is hidden.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Please help me out..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975770/jquery-validation-engine-for-dynamically-added-hidden-input-fields

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields normaly dont change by user, so there is no need to validate hidden fields. If you want to validate it anyway you could change the type attribute to text and add css display:none to it.

Answer (score -1):

Just add 'ignore: "",' in your validation script.

```
$("#form_id").validate(
{
    ignore: "",
    rules: {},
    messages: {}
});
```